# Mixing %s and {} placeholders in postgresql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to set the schema.table_name to a variable, but I also want to pass an integer query 1 works fine when I put it in the python console, but when I call if through a gui it crashes. It only crashes when the %s is present. How can I handle this kind of issue?

In the supplied example below query1 falters but query 2 works.

As you can see I've imported the two necessary libraries.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql 

sample = 10

conn = psycopg2.connect("<details>")
cur = conn.cursor()
print('tables dropped')
query1 = sql.SQL("""CREATE TABLE {}.{} AS 
    (SELECT * FROM {}.{} TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (%s));""").format(
    *map(sql.Identifier, (schema, table_name_top, schema, top_point_cloud))), sample
query2 = sql.SQL("""CREATE TABLE {}.{} AS 
        (SELECT * FROM {}.{} TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (10));""").format(
        *map(sql.Identifier, (schema, table_name_base, schema, base_point_cloud)))
print('query created')
cur.execute(query1)
cur.execute(query2)
```

Comment: What should "%s" be? Also, I would be very surprised if there was not a *useful* error message, as opposed to the non-descriptive "crashes".

Comment: whoops, I've updated it to include the sample variable, the only alter I'm getting from pycharm is that it is not composable, I've been looking at these examoles, but not getting very far http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html